# How to set a Toast inside Ksoap Exception

Tags: android, exception, ksoap

I'm trying to set a Toast when Ksoap get an exception on IOexception or XmlPullParserException. I'm trying with this code in EXCEPTION but i can't show toast.. i guess it's beacuse application got crashed and there is no time to show toast, but I'm not sure... need a help! thank you in advance:

```
    public class RequestWS extends Activity {
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "-------";
    private static String URL="http://-------";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME_SYNCHROAP = "-----";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION_SYNCHROAP = "-----";
    private SoapObject request=null;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=null;
    private Object  resultsRequestSOAP=null;

    public String requestSession() {

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_SESSION);


    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; 

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {   

        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION_SESSION, envelope);
        resultsRequestSOAP = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         RequestWS.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                     Toast.makeText(activity, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                     });

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // NEED THE CORRECT CODE HERE
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    String strJSON = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
    return strJSON;

}
    }
```

I also tried this code inside EXCEPTION, but still not working

```
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

runOnUiThread should have done the task.

One more thing you can try.

Declare a Handler inside your activity and pass it to this function.

```
public String requestSession(final Handler handler) {

...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // NEED THE CORRECT CODE HERE'
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
         Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // NEED THE CORRECT CODE HERE
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
         Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
    e.printStackTrace();

}

...
```

}

Comment: on question, this is activity right... cause if this is the case then you are trying to block UI thread on  resultsRequestSOAP = (Object)envelope.getResponse(); this call. Could you post your entire code for this flow ?

Comment: code updated, yes it's an activity. I'm not sure but I guess the trouble is when trying to pass the context. So you are saying that "resultsRequestSOAP" is blocking the UI thread?, actually I'm getting an exception on "transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION_SESSION, envelope);", just testing the connection request when connection is wrong, so I'm trying to handle the exception showing toast with specific text when the request to this web service is wrong...

Comment: what is activity in this code which passed to :   Toast.makeText(activity, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Ohh ok, this snipped CODE is what I used like possible solution, in my updated code on top the activity I used was RequestWS();, the principal activity.. so I used: "RequestWS.this.runOnUiThread..."